Moodle "Cleanup old sessions" CRON task failing
We're running an up-to-date Moodle environment (version 4.5) and the scheduled task "Cleanup old sessions" (\core\task\session_cleanup_task) keeps failing.  Specifically, it is the call to:
\core\session\manager::gc();

which fails. (The task code is located in \lib\classes\task\session_cleanup_task.php)
I've tried wrapping the call in a try/catch block to report on the message but insainly, no exception is caught, nor does the code return from the call (is this typical in PHP?)
    try {
        \core\session\manager::gc();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      mtrace("gc() failed with message: ".$e->errorMessage());
    }
    

Now, we are using the Microsoft SSO plugins (\local\o365, \auth\oidc, \repository\office365) for a working Single Sign On process which might be somehow related but we can't fathom why the session manager gc call is failing or even why we can't catch the error.  Thanks.

Running in the same problem here. The mdl_sessions table doesn't seem to get any cleaning at all.
I'm just a Moodle admin, not a dev, not a sys admin. I installed Moodle on my machine to try to figure out what was happening. The scheduled tasks runs normally, the sessions folder gets cleaned, but nothing changes in the mdl_sessions table.
So on a busy production site, we can reach millions of entries in mdl_sessions, mostly from userid=0. And I think it causes the task to eventually fail.

I reported the issue in Moodle tracker: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-84051
